# Line to point conversion with start point and end point detection?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am working on converting linestring into points where I also need to detect start point and end point of line. I was able to generate points from linestring to series of points along with start point and end point.

This is the query.

`select foo.line_id, st_astext(st_pointn(geo,generate_series(1,st_npoints(geo)))), st_astext(st_startpoint(geo)), st_astext(st_endpoint(geo)) from temp_line as foo;`

Which results in like bellow(dummy data).

```
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|line_id | st_astext                  | st_astext                  | st_astext                  |
|--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------|
|  6329  | POINT(55.280967 25.216052) | POINT(55.280967 25.216052) | POINT(55.282489 25.215534) |
|  6329  | POINT(55.281085 25.216118) | POINT(55.280967 25.216052) | POINT(55.282489 25.215534) |
|  6329  | POINT(55.281175 25.216151) | POINT(55.280967 25.216052) | POINT(55.282489 25.215534) |
|  6339  | POINT(55.281241 25.216142) | POINT(55.280967 25.216052) | POINT(55.282489 25.215534) |
|  6339  | POINT(55.281323 25.216082) | POINT(55.280967 25.216052) | POINT(55.282489 25.215534) |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Instead of start and end point I want to select a feild with 1 if its a start or end point, else 0.

Like this

```
+--------+----------------------------+-----------+
|line_id | st_astext                  | s_e_point |
|--------+----------------------------+-----------+
|  6329  | POINT(55.280967 25.216052) | 1         |
|  6329  | POINT(55.281085 25.216118) | 0         |
|  6329  | POINT(55.281175 25.216151) | 1         |
|  6339  | POINT(55.281241 25.216142) | 1         |
|  6339  | POINT(55.281323 25.216082) | 1         |
+--------+----------------------------+-----------+
```

Will someone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN path = 1 OR (SELECT ST_NPoints(geom) FROM stackexchange.q_247866 WHERE id = p.id) 
         THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
    END start_end,
    path,
    geom
FROM (
    SELECT
        (dp).path[1] path,
        (dp).geom,
        id
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            (ST_DumpPoints(geom)) dp, -- use geometry_dump format
            id -- keep line id
        FROM stackexchange.q_247866
    ) a
) p;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will explore `ST_DumpPoints()`.
In your above query I am getting `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` error. Any suggestion on that so that I can update your query?

Comment: I updated the query, was testing it with one row only :)

Comment: I wanted both start point and end point to be marked as 1 and rest as 0. And I made a small update in case statement like
 `CASE WHEN path = 1 OR (SELECT ST_NPoints(geom) FROM stackexchange.q_247866 WHERE id = p.id)
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END start_end`. 
Please update your query to accept your answer.

Comment: Answer updated.